# How to find last read index/record from mongodb collection to avoid duplication in further reads?

Tags: mongodb, duplicates

I am reading batch of documents from mongodb. Here I want to fetch next batch from last records read in previous cycle i.e. skipping read records to avoid duplication. Is there any way  to achieve this in C#?

Comment: You should probably research this a bit more before asking. You're essentially asking how to start reading using an offset. Update your question with an example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am reading mongodb documents in a batch of 300 records which gives me 253 documents.
Meanwhile new documents get added to same collection. So, next time when I try to read records from mongodb, i want to skip 253 records those were read in previous cycle. Hence, is there any way to mark records as read or in transit?